# Is there a Java utility class to do data management in a desktop UI?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx-2, data-management

Is there a Java utility class to help with data management in a desktop UI?

I am writing a UI to configure a network device that will be connected to the serial port of the computer while it is being configured. There is no web server for my application.
The UI has a large number of fields (50+) spread across 16 tabs.
I will write the UI in Java (Java FX?). It should run inside the browser when launched, and issue commands to the network device through the serial port. A UI has several input fields spread across tabs and one single Submit button. If a field is edited, and the submit button clicked, it issues a command and sends the new datum to the device, retrieves current value and any errors. so if input field has bad data, it is indicated for example, the field has a red border.

Is there a standard design pattern or Java utility class to accomplish the frequently encountered, 'generic' parts of this scenario? lazy loading, submitting only what fields changed, displaying what fields have errors etc.
(I dont want to reinvent the wheel if it is already there). Otherwise I can write such a class and share it back here if it is useful.

Answer (score 2):

You need a data model : a set of classes with different kind of relationships (UML design may help).

You can learn more about MVC pattern.

Comment: I don't think there is a data model - it is not like the standard employee, employer example in O-O modeling ;) But actually, you have a great point. I shall see if I can come up with a domain specific data model.

Comment: It's probably a bit messy, but you could use hibernate, and write your own datasource to interact with the serial port, rather than a throw sql at a database.

Then you can use any number of MVC frameworks, that work with hibernate.

It's probably more work than writing it yourself.

Comment: It seems a data model would not be useful here - we are just configuring the device.

Answer (score 0):

Java encourages the [Model Control View](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-04-1998/jw-04-howto.html) pattern for separating the levels of responsibility when it comes to the management of data.

Essentianlly the idea is to provide a model that a view can show to the user. The model doesn't care how its displayed nor does the view care about how the data is managed, they simply have an agree dead interface through which they can communicate

Comment: I do know the MVC, Observer-Observable patterns - I am looking for a utility class to accomplish the frequently encountered, 'generic' parts of this scenario. lazy loading, submitting only what fields changed, displaying what fields have errors etc.. I have since clarified the question to reflect this.

Comment: You need a persistence oriented middleware?

Comment: @Aubin Middleware might be a bit much, as most concentrate on providing web interfaces. Anil has said he does not want a web interface.

Comment: @Anil you might consider [JGoodies Bindings](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/libraries/binding/) framework

Comment: There is no database necessary, don't you think? Data is sent to the device to configure it.

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks for the jgoodies bindings link - I shall see if it will work